# GDAL resample 30m file to 90m

Tags: gdal, gdalwarp, srtm, dted

I have an SRTM file in DTED format obtained from [EarthExplorer](https://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/) spanning 1 degree latitude by 1 degree longitude and containing 3601x3601 pixels at 30m spacing. The pixel size resolution is 0.000277777777778.

This file is too large for my purposes, so I want to scale it down, but I have to keep the DTED format.

I tried setting the resolution to 3 x 0.000277777777778 = 0.00083333333:

```
gdalwarp -tr 0.00083333333 0.00083333333 input_file.dt2 downsampled.dt2
```

But this results in a 1200x1200 file, which is not a valid DTED size (I need 1201x1201), so I get this error:

```
Creating output file that is 1200P x 1200L.
Using internal nodata values (e.g. -32767) for image input_file.dt2.
Copying nodata values from source input_file.dt2 to destination .
Warning 1: The source does not appear to be a properly formatted cell.
Warning 1: The corner coordinates of the source are not properly aligned on plain latitude/longitude boundaries.
ERROR 5: Access window out of range in RasterIO().  Requested
(0,0) of size 1201x1 on raster of 1200x1200.
```

What do I need to change to get a valid output file?

**EDIT**: after @user30184 's answer, I tried both of the following:

```sh
gdal_translate -outsize 1201 1201 input_file.dt2 downsampled.dt2
gdalwarp -ts 1201 1201 input_file.dt2 downsampled.dt2
```

However, I still got the warning:

```
The corner coordinates of the source are not properly aligned on plain latitude/longitude boundaries.
```

The original file (3601x3601) covers latitude `[29.9998611,  31.0001389]` and has a pixel size of `0.00027777778`.

The downsampled file (1201x1201) covers latitude `[29.9995833, 31.0004167]` and has a pixel size of 3 x 0.00027777778 = `0.000833333333333`.

After further discussion with @user30184 , **this is a valid result**, as DTED files are supposed to expand outward from the boundaries by 1/2 a pixel size. Thus, **both of the methods proposed in the answer are valid, and I can safely ignore the last warning**.

Comment: Do you need just DTED format for some special application? If not you can convert data into GeoTIFF that is a better DEM format for most software. Then you are not tied to strict resolutions, extents, and pixel sizes of DTED.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define the size of the image instead of the resolution https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_translate.html.

```
gdal_translate -outsize 1201 1201 input_file.dt2 downsampled.dt2
```

Or if you want to use gdalwarp https://gdal.org/programs/gdalwarp.html

```
gdalwarp -ts 1201 1201 input_file.dt2 downsampled.dt2
```

Comment: This seems to almost be perfect! The problem is I still get the warning: `The corner coordinates of the source are not properly aligned on plain latitude/longitude boundaries.` The corner coordinates of the output file seem to have shifted one pixel size down from the original file. Why aren't they the same as the original?

Comment: Try to add `--config DTED_APPLY_PIXEL_IS_POINT TRUE`  https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/dted.html but perhaps you must find out the exact boundaries of the next level tile. The pixel size is changing the extent (measured from the outer edges of the pixels) because the anchor point in DTED is at the centre of the pixel. That's why there are 1201 pixels in a row.

Comment: Oh wait, yeah it didn't shift down, it expanded outward

Comment: The original file spans 1.0002778 degrees latitude. If each pixel is 0.00027777778 apart, wouldn't the pixels across this span be (1.0002778 / 0.00027777778) + 1 = 3602 pixels? The +1 is because there'd be a pixel on each endpoint (the same reason there's 6 numbers when counting from 0 to 5).

Comment: The math doesn't add up to have a pixel right in the center if they are all spaced at 0.00027777778 intervals.

Comment: The standard seems to be available here http://everyspec.com/MIL-PRF/MIL-PRF-080000-99999/MIL-PRF-89020B_25316/.

Comment: The original file spans 1 degree if measured between the centers of outmost pixels. GDAL  reports extent from outer boundaries of pixels and grows values by half a pixel on all sides. GDAL default is "pixel is area" while DTED data are "pixel is point".  Did you try `--config DTED_APPLY_PIXEL_IS_POINT TRUE`? Did is change anything?

Comment: It did not change anything.

Comment: Ah the growing by half a pixel would explain why it doesn't match the math

Comment: If I do `export DTED_APPLY_PIXEL_IS_POINT=1` before the gdal_translate or gdalwarp command, the output latitude boundaries are `[29.9991667, 31.0000000]`, which still doesn't fix the warning

Comment: Please tell what if your actual problem. Do you need to get a valid DTED file with 1201 pixel size and correct extent to some specific program? Or do you expect that the bounds of the new image will remain the same as in the original `[29.9998611, 31.0001389]`? That is not possible because that would be an invalid DTED file, but it is certainly possible to create a valid DTED file by doing the right things.

Comment: I just wanted to convert the file without getting any warnings.  But I see what you're saying, if the new image bounds were still `[29.9998611, 31.0001389]`, then it wouldn't be valid because it's supposed to extend outward half a pixel. And since my pixel size increased, it expands outward more to `[29.9995833, 31.0004167]`.

Comment: If you are confident I can safely ignore the warning, then your original answer is the correct solution.